# How to Reference Requests in Facebook Android SDK 3.6

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have two requests where the output of the first request is the input to the second.
So I made a GET request to obtain current place page id which is the input to second POST request that uses this page id to checkin my current location exactly.

Here is the code of the first GET request:

```
Request.GraphPlaceListCallback callback = new Request.GraphPlaceListCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
                try {
                    placePageID = places.get(0).getInnerJSONObject().getString("id");
                    Log.i("MyFBClient", "Place id is " + placePageID);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Request requestPlacePageID = Request.newPlacesSearchRequest(session,
                myLocation, /* TODO: Error handling may be required */
                1000,
                10,
                null,
                callback
        );
        requestPlacePageID.setBatchEntryName("PlacePageIDReq");
        requestPlacePageID.setBatchEntryOmitResultOnSuccess(false);
```

Here is the code of the second request which is POST:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

postParams.putString("message", " My Text Message ");

postParams.putString("place",/* Here is exactly my problem, how can I reference a place id from the previous GET request?? */ );
        JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
        try {
            coordinates.put("latitude", "30.0380279");
            coordinates.put("longitude","31.2405339");
            Log.i("MyFBClient", "adding latitude and longitude");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("MyFBClient","Exception while adding latitude and longitude");
        }
Request requestPublishStory = new Request(session, /*"me/feed"*/ "me/checkins", postParams,
                    HttpMethod.POST, publishCallback);
requestPublishStory.setBatchEntryDependsOn("PlacePageIDReq"); /* Here I add dependency */
```

Finally, I created the batch request and executed asynchronously:

```
RequestBatch myBatch = new RequestBatch();
        myBatch.add(requestPlacePageID);
        myBatch.add(requestPublishStory);
        myBatch.executeAsync();
```

So Again, I dont know how can I reference my first request output as an input into my second request input? Can anyone have suggestions by the same analogy to [Facebook Advanced Guid](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would do something like:

```
postParams.putString("place", "{result=PlacePageIDReq:$.data.0.id}");
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations for more details.